# Scrolling text with magnifying glass effect

Tags: javascript, css

I want to scroll text like if is passing a magnifying glass, like the image below, but without the actual magnifying glass (and the shadows from it) and possibly also without showing the text as it is entering and leaving the magnifying area.

Is this possible with CSS/CSS3 or (less preferable) JavaScript? Only modern browsers are of interest.

[image]

Comment: CSS cannot even target text nodes, so you are out of luck targeting individual characters. So you would have to put each character in e.g. a span container for a CSS only solution.

Comment: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples  and may be this - http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-frameworks/290795-how-zoom-div-content-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is only possible in JavaScript since CSS doesn't provide a fish-eye filter out of the box. If it's any consolation, it's a pretty lightwight solution. One Google search yielded a working demonstration below (not my code, full credit to [jOlga](https://codepen.io/jOlga)) :

https://codepen.io/jOlga/pen/KyQMQW

```
var bg = document.getElementById('bg'),
    c = document.getElementById('c'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
    src = "https://fstatic1.mtb-news.de/v3/24/2464/2464550-0dx49v9b2nys-14_p9020145-original.jpg";

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width,
        h = this.height;
    
    bg.width = w;
    bg.height = h;
    bg.style.marginLeft = -w/2 + 'px';  
    bg.style.marginTop = -h/2 + 'px';

    bg.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", distortion);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", distortion);
}
img.src = src;

function distortion(e) {
    var cx = (e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX),
        cy = (e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY),
        size = 250,
        zoom = 1.25;
    
    c.width = size;
    c.height = size;
    c.style.left = cx - size / 2 + 'px';
    c.style.top = cy - size / 2 + 'px';
   
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
    ctx.drawImage(
        bg, 
        cx - bg.offsetLeft - .5 * size / zoom, 
        cy - bg.offsetTop - .5 * size / zoom,
        size / zoom,
        size / zoom, 
        0,
        0,
        size,
        size
    );
    
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size);
        pixels = imgData.data,
        pixelsCopy = [], index = 0, h = size, w = size;
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= pixels.length; i+=4) {
        pixelsCopy[index] = [pixels[i], pixels[i+1], pixels[i+2], pixels[i+3]];
        index++;
    }
    
    var result = fisheye(pixelsCopy, w, h);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        index = 4*i;
        if (result[i] != undefined) {
            pixels[index + 0] = result[i][0];
            pixels[index + 1] = result[i][1];
            pixels[index + 2] = result[i][2]; 
            pixels[index + 3] = result[i][3];
        }
    }
    
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function fisheye(srcpixels, w, h) {

    var dstpixels = srcpixels.slice();            
   
    for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {                                

        var ny = ((2*y)/h)-1;                        
        var ny2 = ny*ny;                                

        for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {                            

            var nx = ((2*x)/w)-1;                    
            var nx2 = nx*nx;
            var r = Math.sqrt(nx2+ny2);                

            if (0.0 <= r && r <= 1.0) {                            
                var nr = Math.sqrt(1.0-r*r);            
                nr = (r + (1.0-nr)) / 2.0;

                if (nr <= 1.0) {
                    
                    var theta = Math.atan2(ny,nx);         
                    var nxn = nr*Math.cos(theta);        
                    var nyn = nr*Math.sin(theta);        
                    var x2 = parseInt(((nxn+1)*w)/2);        
                    var y2 = parseInt(((nyn+1)*h)/2);        
                    var srcpos = parseInt(y2*w+x2);            
                    if (srcpos >= 0 & srcpos < w*h) {
                        dstpixels[parseInt(y*w+x)] = srcpixels[srcpos];    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dstpixels;
}
```